# how to trace "depth" or stacking order of a display object?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can you trace the "depth" or stacking order of a display object with AS3?

I'm trying to figure out if my sprite is behind another sprite...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`container.getChildIndex(displayObject);`

but that will only tell you how deep it is, not necessarily if anything is in front of it.

Comment: you can compare child indexes of display objectsbut it only works if they share the same parent. In the generic case I would recommend using one of the implementations that find the closest common ancestor of two display objects and then compare their first uncommon ancestor indexes

Answer (score 2):

Function comparing two DisplayObject instances to determine which one is at a higher "depth" on the display list:

```
private function higher(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
{           
    // Parent chains
    var ac:Array = [a];
    var bc:Array = [b];

    // Pointers to individual nodes
    var an:DisplayObject = a.parent;
    var bn:DisplayObject = b.parent;

    while (an != null) {
        ac.push(an);

        an = an.parent;
    }

    while (bn != null) {
        bc.push(bn);

        bn = bn.parent;
    }

    var acl:int = ac.length;
    var bcl:int = bc.length;

    var n:int = Math.min(acl, bcl);
    var i:int = 0;

    for (; i < n; i++) {
        an = ac[acl - i - 1];
        bn = bc[bcl - i - 1];

        // First uncommon ancestor
        if (an != bn)
            break;
    }

    var ca:DisplayObjectContainer = an.parent;
    if (!ca)
        return null;

    if (ca.getChildIndex(an) > ca.getChildIndex(bn))
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Note: If one of the objects is not on the display list, the function returns `null`. You can change it to return the other object instead.

You can almost certainly optimize this, but this is a first cut.

Answer (score 2):

Just a refactored version of [Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579230/manish) answer using vectors and which won't return weird result if you ever call higher(a,a.parent).

parents() may be used for other purpose too :

```
public function higher(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
{
    var aParents:Vector.<DisplayObject> = parents(a);
    var bParents:Vector.<DisplayObject> = parents(b);
    var commonDepth:int = Math.min(aParents.length, bParents.length);
    for (var depth:int = 0; depth < commonDepth; depth++)
        if (aParents[depth] != bParents[depth])
            break;
    if (depth == 0 || depth == commonDepth)
        return null;
    var commonAncestor:DisplayObjectContainer = aParents[depth].parent;
    if (commonAncestor.getChildIndex(aParents[depth]) > commonAncestor.getChildIndex(bParents[depth]))
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

private function parents(d:DisplayObject):Vector.<DisplayObject>
{
    var result:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>;
    while (d != null)
    {
        result.unshift(d);
        d = d.parent;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems to be working for me. Ran into one gotcha (didn't think about what happens when the objects are at the same depth), so I've posted yet another slight variation on this.

Comment: commonAncestor is the lowest common ancestor of a and b, aParents[depth] != bParents[depth] so they can't have the same child index, unless you have inherited from DisplayObjectContainer end overriden getChildIndex()...there is no such thing as same depth, unless a === b, in which case function can return a or b anyway !

Answer (score 0):

`container.getChildIndex(child)` should do it, it returns the index of the child

Answer (score 0):

```
private function getDepth(clip:DisplayObject):uint
{
    var depth:uint = 0;
    var currentClip:DisplayObject = clip;
    while (currentClip.parent && currentClip.parent != this)
    {
        depth++;
        currentClip = currentClip.parent;
    }
    return depth;
}
```

Comment: typing the parameter as a DisplayObject would be more useful (IE: TextFields, MovieClips, etc.)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Anyway, considering the validated answer I've misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a revised version of what [jauboux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565330/jauboux) did from a version [Manish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579230/manish) did.
Namely, adding a `null` return value from `highestOf()` when depths match.

```
/**
 * @param  ifDepthsMatchReturnObjectA
 * @return  Whichever DisplayObject is higher on the display list.
 *           Optionally returns `null` if they're at the same depth.
 */
public function highestOf(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject, ifDepthsMatchReturnObjectA:Boolean = false):DisplayObject
{
    var aParents:Vector.<DisplayObject> = ancestorsOf(a);
    var bParents:Vector.<DisplayObject> = ancestorsOf(b);
    var commonDepth:int = Math.min(aParents.length, bParents.length);
    for (var depth:int = 0; depth < commonDepth; depth++)
        if (aParents[depth] != bParents[depth])
            break;
    if (depth == 0 || depth == commonDepth)
        return null;
    var commonAncestor:DisplayObjectContainer = aParents[depth].parent;
    var aDepthOnCommonAncestor:int = commonAncestor.getChildIndex(aParents[depth]);
    var bDepthOnCommonAncestor:int = commonAncestor.getChildIndex(bParents[depth]);
    if (aDepthOnCommonAncestor > bDepthOnCommonAncestor)
        return a;
    else if (aDepthOnCommonAncestor < bDepthOnCommonAncestor)
        return b;
    else
        return ifDepthsMatchReturnObjectA ? a : null;
}

/**
 * @return  Whether a is higher than b.
 */
public function isHigher(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Boolean
{
    return highestOf(a, b) === a;
}

/**
 * @return  All ancestors of given display.
 */
private function ancestorsOf(display:DisplayObject):Vector.<DisplayObject>
{
    var result:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>;
    while (display != null)
    {
        result.unshift(display);
        display = display.parent;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: do you have an sample where  "else return ifDepthsMatchReturnObjectA ? a : null;" is usefull ? to me it's just dead code, if depth matches, it just means that a === b. I find it more useful to return null only when a and b don't have a common ancestor